# Using different views in a iMessage App through hiding and showing the views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imessage

I am coding an **iMessage app** at the moment. I have implemented **5 views** into the **messages view controller**. I always want to show one and hide the other 4 depending on which state of the game I am in. I added a URL component to the message but I don't have success with changing the view hiding depending on the path of the URL I am in. For example:

```
base URL: "apple.com/" should show the first view
second URL: "apple.com/secondView/" should show the second view
```

I have the problem that there is not so much about iMessage apps out there. I want the same behaviour like GamePigeon and I am having problems with the view navigation.
Has anyone experienced that and helped me out?

Big thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it via creating Segues from the MessagesViewController and calling them for the state of the different message urls.

```
override func willBecomeActive(with conversation: MSConversation) {
    
    super.willBecomeActive(with: conversation)
    
   
    if let url = conversation.selectedMessage?.url {
        if(url = firstURL {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueIdentifier", sender: self)
        }
        
    }
}
```